# Populating an array with 2 integers randomly in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to fill up a very long array with only 2 values, each index should have either a 0 or a 255 in any random order. How could i do this?  I couldn't find anything about this out there.

Comment: https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-generate-random-numbers take a look here. Instead of calling rand() %100 call rand() %2 + 1 and assign 0 for a value of 1 to your array and  255 for a value of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The  rand()  function returns a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to
>   RAND_MAX inclusive (i.e., the mathematical range [0, RAND_MAX]).
>
> The srand() function sets its argument as the seed for a  new  sequence
>   of  pseudo-random  integers  to be returned by rand().  These sequences
>   are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value.

So you can do for instance :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  int v[10]; /* the 'very long' array */
  int i;

  srand(time(0)); /* random seed */

  /* populating */
  for (i = 0; i != sizeof(v)/sizeof(int); ++i)
    v[i] = (rand() & 1) * 255;

  for (i = 0; i != sizeof(v)/sizeof(int); ++i)
    printf("%d ", v[i]);
  putchar('\n');


  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall r.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
255 0 0 255 0 0 0 255 255 0 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0 255 0 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
255 255 255 0 0 0 255 0 255 0
```

Comment: Just nitpicky; http://c-faq.com/lib/notveryrand.html. I would compare with `MAX_RAND / 2`.